# Unresolved dependency in UnitTesting Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, resilience4j

I getting the following error when trying to write a unit test for CircuitBreaker code example.

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name
>   'com.foosball.team.Service.TeamServiceUnitTest': Unsatisfied
>   dependency expressed through field 'registry'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type
>   'io.github.resilience4j.circuitbreaker.CircuitBreakerRegistry'
>   available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

TeamService:

```
@Service
public class TeamService {

    @Autowired
    private ITeamRepository teamRepository;

    @Autowired
    private PlayerClient playerClient;

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TeamService.class);
    .
    .
    .
```

TeamServiceUnitTest:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = {
        TeamService.class
})
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DirtiesContext
public class TeamServiceUnitTest extends AbstractCircuitBreakerTest {

    @MockBean
    private ITeamRepository teamRepository;

    @MockBean
    private PlayerClient playerClient;

    @Autowired
    private TeamService service;

    private TeamEntity teamEntity;

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TeamServiceUnitTest.class);

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        teamEntity = new TeamEntity();
        teamEntity.setId(1L);
        teamEntity.setPlayerOne("One");
        teamEntity.setPlayerTwo("Two");
        teamEntity.setPlayerThree("Three");
        teamEntity.setPlayerFour("Four");
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("when Player Client Fails 11 Times Then CircuitBreaker Should Be In OPEN State")
    public void whenPlayerClientFailsElevenTimesThenCircuitBreakerShouldBeInOPENState(){
        //Given
        when(teamRepository.findAll()).thenReturn(new ArrayList<>());
        when(playerClient.get(Mockito.anyString())).thenThrow(new RuntimeException());


        //When
        for(int i=0; i<11; i++){
            try {
                service.addTeam(teamEntity);
            } catch (Exception ignore) {
                logger.info(ignore.getClass().getName());
            }
        }

        //Then
        checkHealthStatus(BACKEND_B, CircuitBreaker.State.OPEN);
    }

}
```

Ref Class:

```
public class AbstractCircuitBreakerTest {

    protected static final String BACKEND_A = "backendA";
    protected static final String BACKEND_B = "playerClientCircuitBreaker";

    @Autowired
    protected CircuitBreakerRegistry registry;

    @Before
    public void setup(){
        transitionToClosedState(BACKEND_A);
        transitionToClosedState(BACKEND_B);
    }

    protected void checkHealthStatus(String circuitBreakerName, CircuitBreaker.State state) {
        CircuitBreaker circuitBreaker = registry.circuitBreaker(circuitBreakerName);
        assertThat(circuitBreaker.getState()).isEqualTo(state);
    }

    protected void transitionToOpenState(String circuitBreakerName) {
        CircuitBreaker circuitBreaker = registry.circuitBreaker(circuitBreakerName);
        if(!circuitBreaker.getState().equals(CircuitBreaker.State.OPEN)){
            circuitBreaker.transitionToOpenState();
        }
    }

    protected void transitionToClosedState(String circuitBreakerName) {
        CircuitBreaker circuitBreaker = registry.circuitBreaker(circuitBreakerName);
        if(!circuitBreaker.getState().equals(CircuitBreaker.State.CLOSED)){
            circuitBreaker.transitionToClosedState();
        }
    }
}
```

Ref Project: https://github.com/resilience4j/resilience4j-spring-boot2-demo

Proposed Soln Discussion: https://github.com/resilience4j/resilience4j-spring-boot2-demo/issues/33

Proposed Soln Project: https://github.com/shah-smit/resilience4j-spring-boot2-demo-maven

Comment: Hi @Smit, did you manage to make the test work? I have the problem that the code compiles but the test fails because the circuitbreaker does not open.

Comment: Hi @PauloWeverton can you ensure your computer has enough resources for opening a circuit breaker. When i run the build in Jenkins, the tests passes just fine, but sometime on my computer it doesnt work.

Comment: I do. When a run the application and consume it with a test system, everething goes well, CircuitBreaker with FeignClient, etc. But the junit test don't :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like CircuitBreakerRegistry  you're trying to autowire in you test is a factory class, not a bean. Instead of 
`@Autowired
protected CircuitBreakerRegistry registry;`
Try:
`protected CircuitBreakerRegistry registry = CircuitBreakerRegistry.ofDefaults()`

Comment: Thanks. That solved the issue. May I know, why is the test failing?

Comment: You didn't provide implementaion of TeamService methods so I cannot tell you why. Also i don't know what error message it fails with... Maybe try some debugging.

Comment: I have uploaded the failing the project here: https://github.com/shah-smit/Resilience4j-Spring-Boot-demo may be you can try to help me with resolving it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an answer about not working tests.
Few things here:
1. Using `CircuitBreakerRegistry.ofDefaults()` creates new instance of object each time so this way the `CircuitBreakerRegistry` objects you're using in `AbstractCircuitBreakerTest` and `HomeService` are different instances. You should probably go back to `@Autowired` annotation but first you need to define bean of `CircuitBreakerRegistry` like this:

```
public class CircuitBreakerConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public CircuitBreakerRegistry circuitBreakerRegistry() {
        return CircuitBreakerRegistry.ofDefaults();
    }
}
```

2. You're using `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` but it's just Junit annotation and it does not initialize Spring Context in your test. You're autowiring a bean in your test so you need Spring Context. For this add also `@SpringBootTest` annotation.
3. You're expecting the registry `BACKEND_A` state to change to `OPEN` after 11 calls of `service.getGreeting()` method but I cannot see any usage of `transitionToOpenState` method.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your insights. Here is the project that I referred while working on this project: https://github.com/resilience4j/resilience4j-spring-boot2-demo where transitionToOpenState should happen automatically thats the logic that I am testing.